# Postgres get first item of a group by

Tags: database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I've seen similar questions to this but none seem to quite cover the query I'm trying to build.

I've got a database of request logs to a server, which includes inbound and outbound connections, and I'm trying to get the first item in the log for each request.

The database looks a little like this:
id, requestid, timestamp, message

I want to group by requestid, but get the lowest id from each requestid, which will be the first log item for a request.

I've found similar requests to group by requestid then order by requestid but that doesn't give what I want. I tried adding orderby requestid, id, but that also gives id 2 as the first item that is returned.

This is the closest I've come:
select id, requestid from logs where id in (select distinct on (requestid) id from (select id, requestid from logs order by id) as foo) order by id limit 5;
but the first item returned is id 2, not id 1.

Any tips for this would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/905902

Comment: I looked at that post and tried the Postgres answer in the second answer but that didn't work as I wanted. I've just tried the partition answer in the first, though, and that did work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use an inner join on group by   request id

```
select  id, requestid, timestamp, message
from logs 
inner join  (
    select min(id) as min_id , requestid 
    from logs 
    group by requestid
) t on t.min_id = logs.id and t.requestid = logs.requestid
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. So did the partition answer in the post that was linked to in the comment to my first post. Got two different ways to do it now. Thanks